# Java android ListView update ListView when scroll down

Tags: android, listview

I wanto to update my listVIew when I scroll down my list and I am on a last possition and scroll down I do this but it nor work good

```
    mConnectionList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        private int visibleThreshold = 5;
        private int currentPage = 0;
        private int previousTotal = 0;
        private boolean loading = true;

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if(totalItemCount == previousTotal && currentPage == totalItemCount){
                    getConnections();
                }


        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

    });
```

Comment: use new paging library https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/

Answer (score 0):

A commonly used class which would accomplish this would be the PagedListAdapter class. It allows for the behavior you describe (which is called paging), but you would need to use a recyclerview.

See:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter